# С какой буквы писать слово "империя" или "королевство" в художественной литературе?

Tags: стилистика, прописная-строчная

Я знаю, что официальные названия стран, которые существуют на сегодняшний день, пишутся с большой буквы: "Королевство Таиланд", "Королевство Дания" и т.д.

Но как писать эти слова, например, в вымышленном фэнтези-мире? В "Ведьмаке" Сапковского слово "империя" в русском переводе почему-то пишется с маленькой буквы (Нильфгаардская империя), хотя речь идёт про существующую империю. То же самое с королевствами: "королевство Реданское".

Или эти правила касаются только реального мира? Как правильно писать в данных примерах?

1. Мы знаем, где находится Королевство Батут.
2. Мы знаем, где находится Сирская Империя.
3. Мы знаем, где находится Королевство Урское.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существительные "королевство", "империя" являются **нарицательными** (написание со строчной буквы), но могут входить в **составные имена собственные** и писаться с прописной буквы.

В реальности все слова в **официальных** названиях пишутся с прописной буквы, в других же случаях — только первое слово (например, Римская империя).

В мире фэнтези могут действовать такие же правила, хотя там, как мне кажется, **чаще встречаются варианты** с прописными буквами: Королевство Батут, Сирская Империя, Королевство Урское.

Написание "Нильфгаардская империя" возможно, это выбор автора, но вариант "королевство Реданское" лучше писать как "Королевство Реданское", так как нарицательное существительное стоит на первом месте.